# How to end a infinite while loop with user input

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, loading

I am trying to create a loading sequence of 3 dots that repeats itself until input from the user breaks the loading sequence specifically the enter key. i connot for the life of me get the infinite while loop to end with input

```
public class loop {

    public static void AnyKey() {
        try {
            System.in.read();
            loading(false);
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public static void pause(long duration) {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }

    public static void loading(boolean status){
        if (status == true) {
            while (status) {
                pause(500);
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i <3; i++){
                    System.out.print(".");
                    pause(500);
                }
                System.out.print("\b\b\b");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loading(true);
        AnyKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic:  `if (status == true) { while (status) {` Is doubly redundant. (1) You don't need the `if` since it is followed immediately with a `while` testing the same condition.  (2) You don't need to compare a Boolean expression to `true` or to `false`. In a Boolean expression, `status == true` is the same as `status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I figured it out i needed to learn about and use Threads and global variables check out my code below im fairly pleased with myself i was working on this for 3 days now lol**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class AnyKey extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
        loadingDots.loadingStatus = false;
    }
}
public class loadingDots {
    public static boolean loadingStatus;
    public static void pause(long duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    public static void loading(){
        loadingStatus = true;
        while (loadingStatus) {
            pause(500);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (!loadingStatus){
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(".");
                pause(500);
            }
            System.out.print("\b\b\b");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnyKey anykey = new AnyKey();
        anykey.start();
        loading();
    }
}
```

Comment: The "global variaables" are more accurately called static class fields. I suggest you also read about the so-called "race condition" which is a problem in your code.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code, the main method calls loading and never leaves the function. If you go through `loading(true)` step by step, you find that since `while(status)` is always true you are stuck there and `AnyKey()` is never called.

Also, `System.in.read();` is a blocking call. This means that you will wait for user input but will be unable to print the '...'. Instead I recommend your read [the documentation for input stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), there you will find the `.read()` function but also the `.available()` function which will let you know if any characters have been entered in the input buffer.

Those should be all the tools you need to figure this one out (I think).

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry i still for the life of me cannot figure this out im defenetly mising something major here

Comment: @Mattsimus if you are still having trouble you are probably misunderstanding the way your code is behaving. I recommend you avoid splitting you code into different functions and try to do everything in one function. Everything should fit in a single while loop where you print a '.', check user input, wait 500 milliseconds and loop again.